# Binary Logistic Regression output

Tags: r

I'm an undergrad student and am currently struggling with R, i'be been trying to teach myself for weeks but I'm not a natural, so I thought i'd seek some support.
I'm currently trying to analyse the interaction of my variables on recall of a target using logistic regression, as specified by my tutor. I have a 2 (isolate x control condition)by 2 (similarity/difference list type) study, and my dependent variable is binary of recall (yes or no). I've tried to clean my data and run the code,

```
Call:
glm(formula = Target ~ Condition * List, family = "binomial", 
    data = pro)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8297  -0.3288   0.6444   0.6876   2.4267  

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                1.4663     0.6405   2.289 0.022061 *  
Conditionisolate          -1.1097     0.8082  -1.373 0.169727    
Listsim                   -4.3567     1.2107  -3.599 0.000320 ***
Conditionisolate:Listsim   5.3218     1.4231   3.740 0.000184 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 97.736  on 70  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 65.869  on 67  degrees of freedom
AIC: 73.869
```

that's my output^ it completely ignores the difference and control condition, I know i'm doing something wrong and i'm feeling quite exacerbated by it. Can any one help me?

Comment: "it completely ignores the difference and control condition" — are you sure? Look at the parameter labeled `ConditionIsolate`. It isn't statistically significant but it's in the model.

Comment: I think I may have got myself confused, in my model it refers to each variable as having two levels. I'm very inexperienced in this program, so does that mean that just because it's named Conditionisolate it hasn't only analysed the isolate condition, but both levels of the variable?

Comment: `ConditionIsolate` is the effect of `isolate` *above* the effect of `control`. `control` is generally referred to as the *reference level* and its parameter is zero by assumption. If you want an explicit parameter for both levels then you can set the `contrasts=NULL` on `condition`, but you will have to remove the intercept from the regression or you won't be able to estimate it (you need an identifiability constraint)

Answer (score 0):

In the model output, R is treating control and difference as the baseline levels of your two variables. The outcome associated with them is wrapped up in the intercept. For other combinations of variable levels, the coefficients show how those differ from that baseline.

- Control/Difference: just use the intercept
- Control/Similarity: intercept + listsim
- Isolate/Difference: intercept + conditionisolate
- Isolate/Similarity: intercept + listsim + conditionisolate + conditionisolate:listsim